# Memory Image not appearing in flutter?

Tags: image, dart, base64, flutter

I'm trying to get my Flutter Image.memory to work and I'm only getting a blank space.  I'm trying to do this from a base64 string.  Here is the string...

`SW1hZ2UoaW1hZ2U6IEFzc2V0SW1hZ2UoYnVuZGxlOiBudWxsLCBuYW1lOiAiYXNzZXRzL3BsYWNlaG9sZGVyLnBuZyIpLCBhbGlnbm1lbnQ6IEFsaWdubWVudC5jZW50ZXIp`

Here is my code..

```
Uint8List bytes = BASE64.decode(images);
new Image.memory(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have base64 encoded `Image(image: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/placeholder.png"), alignment: Alignment.center)` this string. Not the bytes of the file.

Try this: https://material.io/icons/#ic_insert_emoticon

`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`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the issue is not with decoding or Image widget. 
The issue is with encoded string.
I gave it a try with another encoded string, where everything seems fine.

You can try converting you image to BASE64 string [here](https://www.base64-image.de/) and use it in your code.